# Concatenate 15,000+ CSV files with different encoding types

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, encoding

I have 15,000+ CSV files which I am trying to merge into one. My problem is...

**How can I concatenate multiple CSV (using glob) when the CSV have different encoding type?**

The two different encoding types of the CSV files are ANSI and UTF-8. I have been looking at lots of Stack Overflow posts related to this, but there is no solid solution available that I can find.

Most posts say something like;
"Try calling read_csv with encoding='latin1', encoding='iso-8859-1' or encoding='cp1252'" Which does not work because there is two different encoding types being used.

Here is my code:

```
#WORKING
#Using GLOB to read every single CSV in a folder 
import glob
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import os
import codecs

path = r'C:\data'
files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
files.sort(key=os.path.getmtime)


li = []

for filename in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0, sep = ' ', skiprows=1, encoding='cp1252', names=['Sec1970', 'VALUE1', 'VALUE2', 'VALUE3', 'VALUE4', 'VALUE5', 'VALUE6'])
    df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('-', '')
    df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(':', '')
    li.append(df)

data = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Error message when using encoding='cp1252

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 96151: character maps to <undefined>
```

Error message when using encoding=utf-8

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf9 in position 48129: invalid start byte
```

I get an error no matter what encoding type I use. I have two questions...

- Can I somehow read CSV files with my code/method shown above with both ASCII and UTF-8 encoding?
- If I can not use both ASCII and UTF-8 encoding, what is a suitable method to change the encoding type of 15,000+ CSV files?

Comment: https://krinkere.github.io/krinkersite/encoding_csv_file_python.html. Go ahead and check the encoding of the csv before reading into the dataframe. Or just catch the error and try the other encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slight modification you can make to your code to catch the exception:

```py
#WORKING
#Using GLOB to read every single CSV in a folder 
import glob
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import os
import codecs

path = r'C:\data'
files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
files.sort(key=os.path.getmtime)


li = []

for filename in files:
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0, sep = ' ', skiprows=1, encoding='utf-8', names=['Sec1970', 'VALUE1', 'VALUE2', 'VALUE3', 'VALUE4', 'VALUE5', 'VALUE6'])
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0, sep = ' ', skiprows=1, encoding='cp1252', names=['Sec1970', 'VALUE1', 'VALUE2', 'VALUE3', 'VALUE4', 'VALUE5', 'VALUE6'])
    df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('-', '')
    df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(':', '')
    li.append(df)

data = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```